# Testing TLS compatability after switch over - is GET a lone OK?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, ssl

We are switching over from SSL to TLS on our production web servers.

We have a web services which we have hundreds of clients consuming, and we are agnostic for how they are doing this.

We want to provide them a test site which will use TLS and ask them to confirm that their current code/consumer is working fine on TLS, before we switch it over in production.

Will a GET only be sufficient for them to test against? OR, do we need them to test POST, PUT, etc, and all other verbs they may be using?

In case this mattered, this is an ASP.NET MVC 3 REST web service.

Thanks,

Drew

Comment: Would have taken you less time to add tests for each verb than it did to write this question :/

Comment: @Will we have no idea what API or client our clients are using. Obviously we need them to test it themselves

Answer (score 0):

A GET will be sufficient since the TLS handshake is no different between GET, POST etc. But if you require client certificates in selected directories be sure that the Test-URL includes this requirement too.